# asp.net mvc why ajax response after refreshing the page

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

**this method I'm writing database and folder operations. no problem at all
the response is coming but the page refreshes. The problem disappears when I cancel folder operations.I don't want the page refreshed**

```
 $(".btnSave").on("click", function (e) {

    var model = {
        "ProductName": productName, "BrandCategoryId": BrandCategoryId, "TaxRate": taxRate, "WareHouseId": WareHouseId, "ProductId": ProductId, "PurchasePrice": purchasePrice, "Count": count, "Discount": discount
    };
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    swal({
        title: "Lütfen Bekleyin", text: "Stok kayıt yapılıyor..", showConfirmButton: false, allowOutsideClick: false
    });
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/Warehouseworker/JavaScript/NewStock",
        data: model,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.ModelErrors) {
                var errors = response.ModelErrors;
                swal.close();
                showErrors(errors);
            }
            if (response.errorMsg) {
                swal({ title: "Uyarı", text: "hata var", type: "warning" });
            }
            if (response.success) {
                swal({ title: "Stok kaydı gerçekleştirilmiştir", text: "", type: "success" });

            }

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Why do you have `window.location.reload();` if you do not want to reload it?

Comment: I've been trying something, but it's not the problem

Comment: Are there any script errors in the debug console?

Comment: I found problem. Visual studio browser reload on save. This is the problem

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a button and it is in a form?

If so, make the button `type="button"` and it won't refresh the page. The default behavior is to post the form that it is in.

It it's a link then add the `href=javascript:;`.